# /s/ or /z/ in ending of [long vowel] + "se" or "s"

Tags: english, phonology, etymology, historical-linguistics

Are there any rules regarding the pronunciation of "se" or "s" in the ending
[long vowel] + "se" or "s"?

/z/: tease, browse

/s/: lease, house

English pronunciation pod in the reference just lists some exceptional words which end with "se" and the "se" pronounced as /z/.

Reference: http://www.englishpronunciationpod.com/podcast_44.html, Oxford dictionary, and Cambridge dictionary

Comment: Maybe this is better asked on the English Learner's stackexchange at http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a trend: if it's a noun, it's [s], and if it's a verb, it's [z]. This generates noun / verb alternations like "house" (s/z). The reason is that *s* became *z* between vowels, except those deleted earlier; and then more words were added.

Comment: @user6726 Where do you read about this trend?

Comment: @pterodragon, dunno, it's one of those common knowledge about history of English things that we learned in class eons ago and talk about. I guess I would ask the local History of English professor.

Comment: This trend also applies to other fricatives, sometimes with a change of vowel: _breath/breathe_; _half/halve_; _calf/calve_; _life/live_; _mouth/mouth_; _wreath/wreathe_.

Comment: @jknappen. I think this question is fine if it is taken as being about etymology.

Comment: @fdb Maybe I should have asked about why, not the rules regarding those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, consonants at the end of a word remained voiceless, while those between vowels became voiced. Thus the singular noun “house” comes from Old English hus, the verb “to house” from OE husian. The other examples mentioned by Colin Fine are of the same nature.